# Seeing an odd error message in Chrome console window?

Tags: google-chrome

I get this strange error in Chrome's console window:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
  extensions::messaging:73PortImpl.postMessage 
  extensions::messaging:73publicClass.(anonymous function)  
  extensions::utils:93onVisibilityChange page-state-tracker.js:8
```

How do I determine which browser extension is causing this?

clicking `extensions::messaging` says something about catch error to an ajax post?? This is concerning as I'm thinking I have some kind of rogue malware/spyware extension..

Does anyone know how I can determine the extension causing this?

Comment: Visiting `about:plugins` and `about:extensions` should give you some idea of the 3rd party things hooked into chrome.

Comment: Have you unloaded all the extensions and plugins listed and then re-enabled one by one to see when the error re-appears?

Comment: no I was trying to avoid doing that.. i have about 40 extensions..  the error happens rarely at random times.. i have seen it in the past while developing.. doing it that way is just way to tedious

Comment: `locate manifest.json | xargs -I{} grep -i "page-state-tracker.js" "{}"` or similar with find. That will look through all the manifest.json, which contain the resources of the extensions, which should define the misbehaving page-state-tracker.js

Comment: looks like it is live-reload extension.. now how do I figure out if it is acting maliciously or not? was it posting to my localhost server .. is their a log or something that would give me this info?

Comment: You could always look into the actual extension resources to see what it is doing... 'Acting maliciously' is a pretty nebulous term but in general we don't really have good behavior based detection schemes for malware. If it hasn't been blacklisted you'd have to do the investigation yourself to see whether it's malicious or not.

Answer (score 8):

For me it ended up being Awesome Screenshot 3.7.21_0.  Found it using the following command:

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions -name "manifest.json" -exec grep -H "page-state-tracker.js" {} \;
```

Since the extensions are anonymously named, you'll need to probe around a bit to figure out which extension you're dealing with.

If you're not using a mac you'll need to look for the extensions in the proper directory:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862215/what-is-a-manifest-json-file-and-where-can-i-find-it-on-my-machine

Comment: Thanks for doing the search, that extension was the culprit for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome extensions define their resources in a file called manifest.json.

Since the error message you are describing calls out page-state-tracker.js you could search through all your system's manifest.json files trying to find one that has a resource which is causing your problem by using something like: `locate manifest.json | xargs -I{} grep -i "page-state-tracker.js" "{}"` or `find / -name 'manifest.json' -exec grep -i "page-state-tracker.js" {} \;`