# How to find out which chrome extension is producing an error?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In my JavaScript console of the chrome devtools are several extension errors shown. Is there a better way then deactivating each extension to find out which one produces the error?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/809401/seeing-an-odd-error-message-in-chrome-console-window

Comment: @DavidPostill because I would like to know in general, if there is a quick way to find out. I know the specific error was raised by the adblock-extension, but I had to google it to find out. I had at least 2 incidents in the past, when I was unable to find a solution even with extensive research, where I ended up in the tedious process of deactivating one extension at a time.